Is this the right place to get feedback on an idea?
I would like to propose a novel definition of fractal dimension.   It isn't really a question, more a request for feedback.  I don't want to get slammed with down votes.   Can I do this here? I suppose I could frame it like a question.  I could say, "does this definition have problems", but that is sort of being deceptive.

Unfortunately, this is not the correct place for this. Speak to expert in the field, be patient, humble, and polite, and you should get an answer. Humble is particularly important, I've had my fair share of people asking me a question about uncountable sets, or CH, or whatever, just to then attack all of set theory when receiving an email pointing out their mistakes (and sometimes emails that were just immediately condescending, and therefore received no reply at all).

Why would someone down vote an honest question?  Everybody is so negative today.

@Chris on meta downvotes indicate disagreement with the premise of the question, not that it's a bad question (this gets discussed regularly, you can search for it).  The downvotes are just supporting Asaf's comment, nothing more.  You also don't get a reputation change from downvotes on meta.

Generally speaking, one solves a problem first, and then defines terms in order to make it easier to explain the problem and its solution.  No one really cares if you are introducing a new definition.  What problem are you solving, and how does you new definition make it easier to communicate that problem and its solution?  The kind of question proposed in this post is not appropriate for Math SE.  However, if you have a question about the actual problem you are trying to solve, that would probably be on-topic.

@Chris: when you ask "Can I do this here?", what do you mean by "here"? Do you mean "here on Meta", or "here on MSE"? In the first case, the answer is "no", because Meta is reserved for questions about the functionalities of MSE. In the second case the answer is "yes".

You make me really curious what that definition will look like :-)

@AlexM.    Good my point, yes my question was ambiguous.  By "here" I did not mean on "Meta", but rather on stack exchange.  By the way, my question keeps adding down votes.  Does anybody who is giving it a down vote want to explain why?

@Chris: I did not downvote, but the answer to your question being "yes", just stop tormenting yourself over the downvotes and go ahead and ask your question on the main site.

I just saw and voted up the question on main. It's certainly appropriate (about the question itself, I certainly understand and appreciate where it came from but don't have an answer yet).

@Dominique I have posted the question.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5003799/is-this-novel-fractal-dimension-related-to-the-conventional-ball-counting-dimens. I know I'm acting a bit silly, but I hope I don't get a bunch of down votes.

One might ask about logical equivalence of your preferred definition and any of the several well-known definitions of fractal dimension.  That's a reasonable problem statement, but context is also required.  You should research this problem before posting, and support your interest in the problem in at least one of several ways.
Where did you encounter the problem?  What makes it difficult or important?  Are there some similar or partial results you can present? Etc.

A comparison of OP's proposed definition with more than one existing definition is too broad, in my opinion. So "any of the several" is fine as long as comparison with different dimension notions are kept as separate questions.

@hardmath  I might follow your suggestion.  The question would be phrased as: "Is this definition of a fractal definition equivalent to the Minkowski ball counting definition"?  I hope I don't get a bunch of down votes.
